# If the yellow dot disappears but Mathematica claims to still be "running", is it really running?

Tags: equation-solving

So I've been performing a particular computation for a few days now and in this period the Mathematica tab on my Windows layout had a yellow dot on it, to signify that it was running a computation. However, the yellow dot disappeared, but the computation is not yet done and if I open the software then it also claims to still be performing the computation.

I couldn't find this question anywhere else, so I pose it here: is Mathematica *really* still running?

Comment: You are lucky, I have never seen any yellow dot or any other indication that Mathematica was running on 3 different Linuxes and Windows.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I think it is a Windows OS issue and not a Mathematica issue.

Comment: You also might check TaskManager

Comment: @bobbym  I think that this is a recent addition to Mathematica.  I see it on Version 11 under Windows 10.  It appears on the lower right cornet of the Mathematica icon on the taskbar.

Comment: @m_goldberg  This appears to be a Mathematica feature, not a windows feature.

Comment: @bbgodfrey It appears on TaskManager, but so does my Latex compiler, which is completely "passive". Thus I would guess that it appears on my TaskManager for the fact that it is "open" as a software rather than because it is performing any kind of computation.

Comment: You are correct.  However, are any of the two or more Mathematica processes using CPU time?  If not, Mathematica probably is not running.  While you have Task Manager open, see how much memory is in use.  Sometimes, Mathematica devours all memory and grinds to a halt.

Comment: @bbgodfrey "Wolfram Mathematica 11" is using 0% CPU while "Wolfram Kernel for Windows" is using 17% CPU (out of 21% I think). I don't know exactly what to make of that. I suppose that means it's running?

Comment: It's definitely running.  The question now is, is it doing anything useful.  Who can say.

Comment: I have joined others in voting to close this question.  Without additional information it does not seem possible to provide any useful reply.  If I am mistaken and someone knows how to snoop on a running Kernel to determine where your program is in its computation I will gladly reopen this question for them to post.

Comment: @bobbym In windows settings you need to search for "show badges on taskbar" and enable it.